# RajawaliVR how to draw Crosshair?

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, photosphere, rajawalivr

I have started using RajawaliVR framework.

I am able to display **photo sphere images** and able to change **dynamically** on click.

**But now I want to change image without click. But how ?**

I have rough idea to do this but stuck at implementation.

I have **draw one circle on photo sphere image** at particular **x,y position** say x=1935 and y=1495.

**Image size is = 3840 X 2160.**

Now when **center of my eyeview** is match to **circle point on image** at (x=1935 and y=1495) want to change image.

Please See the picture below for more clarity.

[image]

Comment: Have you had any success in implementing this? Thanks